# Quarkus Getting Started (w/ Reactive): PostGres/Docker CRUD Application -- Missing POST, PUT, and DELETE REST URLs

Tags: json, rest, http, jax-rs, quarkus

I'm going through the Quarkus - Getting Started w/ Reactive tutorial, which features a so-called 'CRUD' application.  The tutorial skips over how to translate the code below into RESTful URLs.  Any hints about where to go for guidance etc. would be greatly appreciated. FYI, my attempts so far have returned a 404 Error with the following list of "REST resources":

- PUT fruits{id}  Consumes: application/json Produces: application/json
- DELETE fruits{id}  Consumes: application/json Produces:
  application/json
- GET fruits{id}  Consumes: application/json Produces:
  application/json
- GET fruits  Consumes: application/json Produces:
  application/json
- POST fruits  Consumes: application/json Produces:
  application/json

Code from tutorial: [Quarkus - Getting started with Reactive](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-reactive)

```
 @GET
public Multi<Fruit> get() {
    return Fruit.findAll(client);
}

@GET
@Path("{id}")
public Uni<Response> getSingle(@PathParam Long id) {
    return Fruit.findById(client, id)
            .onItem().apply(fruit -> fruit != null ? Response.ok(fruit) : Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND))
            .onItem().apply(ResponseBuilder::build);
}

@POST
public Uni<Response> create(Fruit fruit) {
    return fruit.save(client)
            .onItem().apply(id -> URI.create("/fruits/" + id))
            .onItem().apply(uri -> Response.created(uri).build());
}

@PUT
@Path("{id}")
public Uni<Response> update(@PathParam Long id, Fruit fruit) {
    return fruit.update(client)
            .onItem().apply(updated -> updated ? Status.OK : Status.NOT_FOUND)
            .onItem().apply(status -> Response.status(status).build());
}

@DELETE
@Path("{id}")
public Uni<Response> delete(@PathParam Long id) {
    return Fruit.delete(client, id)
            .onItem().apply(deleted -> deleted ? Status.NO_CONTENT : Status.NOT_FOUND)
            .onItem().apply(status -> Response.status(status).build());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, do you have `quarkus-resteasy-mutiny` as a dependency? If not, you will need that. Next, `Multi` typically is used to return SSE. If you want to return a list return a `Uni<List<T>>`. Multiple `onItem` will probably work, but it looks odd. I’d suggest using `map` instead. Give those few things a try and see what you get.

Comment: actually GET annotated methods slash RESTful URL's work as expected, i.e., **http://localhost:8080/fruits/** returns: _[{"id":2,"name":"Durian"},{"id":1,"name":"Kiwi"},{"id":4,"name":"Lychee"},{"id":3,"name":"Pomelo"}]_ and **http://localhost:8080/fruits/2** returns: {"id":2,"name":"Durian"}.  Which is to say, everything is working flawlessly; I haven't figured out yet how to put together a RESTful URL that maps to the POST, PUT, and DELETE annotated methods, however.